# execute java from php from different directory

Tags: java, php

I have linux server(Debian). I have java program(compiled) in directory (reza). I am trying to execute this java program from /var/www and through php script.

```
$com=shell_exec('java /reza/z');
```

When call in above format it dosent return any results or execute java program. 
When I call one php script in reza folder with same call format it returns correct response:

```
$com=shell_exec('php /reza/a.php');
```

Any idea how to make this to work correctlly?

P.S. when call java from same directory from php it returns correct response:

```
$com=shell_exec('java z');
```

Java file is compiled and include class file too.

Java sample code is:

```
    import java.io.*;

public class z{

   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

      File file = new File("Hello1.txt");
      // creates the file
      file.createNewFile();
      // creates a FileWriter Object
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
      // Writes the content to the file
      writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n"); 
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();

      //Creates a FileReader Object
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
      char [] a = new char[50];
      fr.read(a); // reads the content to the array
      for(char c : a)
          System.out.print(c); //prints the characters one by one
      fr.close();
   }
}
```

Regards,

Finally solved this. Must change permission of target folder and enable "Write" too. Thanks all for helping me.

Comment: have you checked your server logs?

Comment: Yes, no errors in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the classpath switch:

```
$com=shell_exec('java -cp /reza z');
```

Comment: tried that before and now again, but not works and return this: $com=shell_exec('java z');

Comment: Does your z class have a package identifier in it?

Comment: Not. I used simple simple code to return one string only.

Comment: So your z.java file doesn't start with `package reza;`

Comment: Can you post an update that has 1) The command you used to How the compile the z, 2)  The z.java file, 3) What is your expected result in PHP

Comment: No and "reza" is my directory name and in java code there is not any "reza" text.

Comment: Compile like this:   javac z.java

Comment: If you go into  interactive mode in php (>php -a) from a directory other than /reza what happens when you enter `shell_exec('java -cp /reza z');`

Comment: When use this: shell_exec('java -cp /reza z'); nothing happen

Comment: That means it's working, because if you were to run `shell_exec('java /reza/z');` in the interactive shell, then I bet you it would say something like: `Error: Could not find or load main class .reza.z`

Comment: Question is, when it works must generates one txt file and return string, but nothing. But when call from in same directory and without any path, it works correctly. I tried one simple code and only try return one string and it works correct again. But for above java code when call from another directory not work.

Comment: Well that's weird I'm able to get it to work on my machine with the `shell_exec('java -cp /reza z');` call from another directory. Are you sure the file is not getting created when you do that? Maybe try and change the file in java to make sure. Example: `File file = new File("/home/youruserdir/Hello1.txt");`

Comment: Did you run from php or java?

Comment: tried this too: File file = new File("/home/youruserdir/Hello1.txt"); but results are same before

Comment: Well, thanks for trying my suggestions. too bad we couldn't getting working. However, having the right `shell_exec('java -cp /reza z');` should at least get you going in the right direction. If you do ever end up solving this, please post your solution as an answer to your post here. It could help others in the future.

Comment: Sure, do you think maybe problem in my java code? because when try new java code it works.

Comment: I'm not sure. I had assumed that it would have been working ever since changing the `shell_exec` command, but maybe you weren't seeing the results for some reason. Glad it's working now :) Thanks for selecting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the full path to Java executible in command (/usr/bin/java for example) . You may also need to set up class path etc with arguments. Remember that Java is executing in the context of the web server user, not your personal login, so the environment may not have the same variables defined with same values, such as JRE_HOME, PATH etc.

To find out what you have shell exec the env command to list the available environment variables, with php. I think phpinfo() will give you the same info.

Comment: I tried find error. It returns this: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006) at z.main(z.java:9)